# Putting tables together with rbind

Tags: r, tidyverse, rbind, cbind

I'm wondering if someone can help me figure out how to best go about this problem. Essentially I have two tables that I'm trying to put together in one:

Table 1 looks something like:

```
sex      n
Male     54.1
Female   45.9
```

and Table 2 looks like:

```
agegroup      n
18-24         8.2
25-34         13.3
35-44         12.2
```

What I want is a single table that looks something like this (with space between table 1 and table 2):

```
Gender      
Male     54.1
Female   45.9

Age Group      
18-24         8.2
25-34         13.3
35-44         12.2
```

I tried using rbind() to start the process, but if I do rbind(Table1, Table2), I get this:

```
sex      n      agegroup      
Male     54.1   
Female   45.9
         8.2    18-24
         13.3   25-34
         12.2   35-44
```

Would appreciate if anyone knew how I could go with the preferred output above (preferably with the space between the two tables?) Thanks!

Comment: Your desired output should _not_ be in a single data table or data frame, because the two sets of columns don't have the same type.  Rather, the output you want should be generated when you want to see.  Keep your data in two separate tables.

Answer (score 3):

You probably come from an Excel background and want something like a work sheet also in `R`. Tim Biegeleisen pointed out in his comment that this does not work in `R`. What you could do, if you want to keep related things together - you could use a **list**. Copying your data from the clipboard with

```
Gender <- read.table( "clipboard", header = TRUE )
Age_Group <- read.table( "clipboard", header = TRUE )
```

I combined them in then into a list with

```
my_Excel_like_table <- list( "Gender" = Gender, "Age_Group" = Age_Group )
```

which gives you

```
> my_Excel_like_table
$Gender
     sex    n
1   Male 54.1
2 Female 45.9

$Age_Group
  agegroup    n
1    18-24  8.2
2    25-34 13.3
3    35-44 12.2
```

So this looks a bit like your expectation.

You can now reference your data with

```
> my_Excel_like_table[["Gender"]]
     sex    n
1   Male 54.1
2 Female 45.9

> my_Excel_like_table[["Gender"]][2]
     n
1 54.1
2 45.9

> my_Excel_like_table[["Gender"]][,2]
[1] 54.1 45.9

> my_Excel_like_table[["Gender"]][2,]
     sex    n
2 Female 45.9

> my_Excel_like_table[["Age_Group"]][3,"n"]
[1] 12.2
```

`list`s are very powerful and you might want to study more from the usual `R` manuals and tutorials.